# Google Sheets script: Using a term in one cell to delete a row on another page

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I’m trying to find a way to delete a row on one sheet based on a row selected by a checkbox on another sheet, using an onEdit function.

The checkbox is in Column A on **Sheet1**; the row is variable, since Sheet1 is a search page. The unique search result / search string is in **Column B**. The records that I want to delete from this search page are on a second sheet, **Sheet2**. In Sheet2, some of the same data is duplicated from Sheet1, but there’s no checkbox. So, the unique identifier in Column *B* on Sheet1 is Column *A* on Sheet2, and that’s where I want the deletions to happen. In Sheet2, the Column A values are *always* unique, so I wouldn't think this calls for an array.

So, to summarize, this script would say: if a row on Sheet1 is checked, look at the value of Column B in that row. Then, search **Column A in Sheet2**. If matched, deleteRow. So, my question is: **How would this script be written?**

**However**, there’s one slight complication, which I hesitate to mention for fear that the question will face closure due to “lack of focus.” **(so, if you just want to answer the above and ignore this bit, that's still wonderful!)**. I'm only asking because I feel like it affects how the script would be coded in the first place. I only want this deletion to happen if **Column E** on Sheet1 says **Indirect**. If Column E is *blank*, or contains other text, then the script runs as follows:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart != 1) return;
  if (e.value != 'TRUE') return;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ignored_sheets = ['Sheet2','Sheet3'];
  if (ignored_sheets.includes(sheet.getName())) return;
  if(e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(),5).getValue().length > 0){ 
    sheet.toast("Can't overwrite data.");
    sheet.getActiveCell().setValue(false);
    return;};
  var row_index = e.range.rowStart;
  var row = sheet.getRange('B' + row_index + ':D' + row_index).getDisplayValues().flat();
  if (row[1] == '') return; 
  var result = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .alert("Append record?", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if (result != SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    sheet.toast("Operation canceled.");
    sheet.getActiveCell().setValue(false);
    return;}
  sheet.toast("Operation complete.");
  sheet.getActiveCell().setValue(false);
  sheet.getRange('B3').clearContent();
  sheet.getSheetByName('Sheet2').appendRow(row);
  sheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').setActiveCell('B3');
}
```

Comment: In the code, above you didn't used any method which delete row in Sheet2, So to summarize your problem as much i understood from problem statement above, for example:- If user on Sheet 1 click on checkbox in Column A, you want to get the string from Column B and you want script to search the string in Sheet 2 and if it founds it, you want it to delete the row in sheet 2, right???

Comment: Yes, exactly. The script is doing two functions right now: adding records where appropriate and blocking edits where necessary. The third function I want to add is the ability to delete records, if their column E value is "Indirect".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per problem statement you mentioned in comments:-

> The third function I want to add is the ability to delete records, if
> their column E value is "Indirect"

Sample script will look like this :-

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  const value = e.value
  const range = e.range
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const row = range.getRow();
  const column = range.getColumn();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const checkValue = sheet.getRange(row, 5).getValue(); // Column E value
  if(column === 1 && value == 'TRUE' && checkValue === 'Indirect')
  { 
    const ref_IDtoSearch = sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue(); // ref id in sheet 1
    const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2')
    const refRange = targetSheet.getRange('A1:A').getValues().flat(); // Range ref column in sheet 2
    const posRow = refRange.indexOf(ref_IDtoSearch)
    if(posRow > -1)
    {
      targetSheet.deleteRow(posRow+1)
    }
  }
}
```

Incorporate it in your existing `onEdit` code.

**Reference:**

[deleteRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowrowposition)

Comment: That's beautiful. I made two tweaks in deployment. 1. I changed another part of the script:
`if(e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(),5).getValue().length > 0 **&& checkValue != 'Indirect'**)`

Now, the 2 parts of the function don't interfere w/ each other. 2. I added a confirmation dialog box. Placing the code flummoxed me briefly, but I got it. The UI & false/cancel condition went right after your code's first IF, and before the refIDtosearch constant. The OK condition w/ a toast msg. & search box reset, went right after the close brace on the deleteRow command. Thanks so much!

Comment: Purpose of above code, is to give you an idea of how you can delete the rows, I'm glad it helped. For documentation purpose, you can mark this answer as accepted to make it reference point for future sailors